# how to initial TabController when using get as the state manage component

Tags: flutter

I want to use TabBarView in the flutter UI, now using [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) as the state management, this is my UI code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import 'dev_word_controller.dart';

class DevWord extends StatelessWidget {
  DevWord({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  List tabs = ["生词", "已记住", "全部"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    TabController _tabController = TabController( length: tabs.length, vsync: this);

    void _handleTabSelection() {
      if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
        switch (_tabController.index) {
          case 0:
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('Page 1 tapped.'),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            ));
            break;
          case 1:
            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
              content: Text('Page 2 tapped.'),
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            ));
            break;
        }
      }
    }

    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);

    return GetBuilder<DevWordController>(
        init: DevWordController(),
        builder: (controller) {
          return DefaultTabController(
            length: tabs.length,
            child: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                    bottom:PreferredSize( 
                      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1),
                        child:Material(
                          color: Colors.green,
                        child:TabBar(
                            indicatorColor: Colors.black,
                            labelColor: Colors.white,
                            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.yellow,
                            tabs: tabs.map((e) => Tab(text: e)).toList())))),
                body: SafeArea(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: tabs.map((e) {
                      return ListView(children: controller.getCurrentRender);
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                )),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

this line code `TabController _tabController = TabController( length: tabs.length, vsync: this);` show this error:

```
The argument type 'DevWord' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TickerProvider'.
```

what should I do to initial the TabController, because I am using get, so I did not want to create another state in the code.

Answer (score 2):

please check tab controller documentation,
[1]: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController-class.html

you need to include SingleTickerProviderStateMixin for custom tab controller

or use DefaultTabController with stateless widget approach